# Stack element above two arrows

Tags: math-mode, overset

I'm trying to put an element above a left- and right arrow stacked above eachother.
This is the bit of code:

```
$S\overset{e}{\substack{\rightarrow\\[-1em] \leftarrow}} P$
```

What I get is that the e has an arrow going through it. The e should be above. Any help in doing this is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! It may be good to know can format a block of code by indenting it by four spaces like I've just done (you can do this by selecting it and pressing the "{}" button at the top or pressing ctrl-K (or cmd-K on a Mac)) and you can format inline code by surrounding it by `\`…\``.

Comment: You were probably looking for `\leftrightarrows` by the way (requires [`amssymb`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb), unless you're using a font that already includes it).

Comment: @Circumscribe Oops, that was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Many symbols that you might be looking to create already exist, so the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/156366) may be useful to you.